# How to limit one field only in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating something like fb... I want to show 3 comments only on home page... How to limit one field only... my schema is this:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    admin: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: [{ 
        postId: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'posts', required: true },
        admin: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true },
        comment: { type: String, required: true },
        time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }],
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modified: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

I have all comments in an array... I want to limit them... Please help

Comment: How did you solve this at the end? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#slice-projection) (projection) in MongoDB. The $slice operator controls the number of items of an array that a query returns.

If you want to fetch first 3 comments only then your query will be as below:

```
db.slice.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: 3 } } )
```

In case if you want last 3 comments then your query will be:

```
db.slice.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -3 } } )
```